# Heroku mvn not found error

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I  have one java application  which is running in my local machine . I pushed it in to heroku  now when I am trying to run it by run the command 
heroku run “mvn exec:java –Dexec.mainClass=”my main class””

it is giving

sh: mvn: not found

previously it was working fine  I run that with same command  now it is giving this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We removed mvn from the compiled slug in an update a few weeks ago. You can read more about it here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-note-java-2011-09-29

In case you're wondering why you couldn't find this article, we just published it. Apologize for the delay.

Comment: can you plz let me now how can i run my java package now?

Comment: It should be covered in the article linked to above. If you're using the appassembler plugin, just make sure it copies jars into target. This is the default behavior, so just make sure you *don't* have the line <generateRepository>false</generateRepository> in your POM. See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java for a quick start on deploying Maven apps to Heroku